# ClickOnce-signing on continuous integration server only

Tags: .net, ms-office, clickonce

**Context**:
We are multiple developers that are working on a single Office addin. Our continuous integration (CI) server creates deployable artifacts.

However, Visual Studio enforces every developer to sign the ClickOnce manifest (disabling the checkbox "Sign the ClickOnce manifests" in the project properties will re-check it on the next build). Thus every developer needs to be in possession of the signing certificate.

Is there a way to disable signing the manifest for the developers?

Note: We do not want to eventually deploy without a signed manifest, but we want to *keep the signing certificate on a single machine*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We now solved this for us as follows:

1. We created a "development-only" certificate that is self-signed, expires in many years and is under version-control. All developers share this certificate, but it can't be used to create installers signed by our company.
2. The continuous integration server will update the application manifest and create a new deployment manifest using [Mage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acz3y3te.aspx) (using the real signing certificate)

While this does not **disable** signing on the development machines, it avoids the problems associated with sharing the trusted certificate on all development machines.

Comment: I know this is old but I can't find the answer anywhere. How are you getting you CI to build, and deploy and click once application?

Comment: There are command-line tools to handle that. I think the most important one was called mage. Quick google revealed that blog post: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsto/2009/04/29/signing-and-re-signing-manifests-in-clickonce-saurabh-bhatia/

I hope that helps you to get started.

Comment: @NobodysNightmare I also came upon same scenario? Isn't there any way just to skip signing the manifests/application files, in machine which don't have certificate (I am hoping to implement that logic in build script somehow)

Comment: We were currently resigning the same way, as you mentioned. But, it felt that there should be the smarter way to do it, instead of signing it during build process and again resigning post-build using Mage tool.